# SQLite Exception near "course_gpa_id"

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

I encountered some exceptions while writing my DatabaseHandler, I've corrected most of the errors, but this one appeared recently when I though I was just done with debbuging.

This is my SQL statement. All 3 other tables give no error and are created correctly. This is the last create table statement.

```
private static final String CREATE_COURSE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_COURSE + " (" + KEY_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_COURSEPROF_ID
        + " INTEGER, " + FOREIGN_PROF + ", " + KEY_COURSEGPA_ID
        + " INTEGER, " + FOREIGN_GPA + ", " + KEY_COURSETERM_ID
        + " INTEGER, " + FOREIGN_TERM + ", " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_COURSE_NUMBER + " TEXT, " + KEY_COURSE_LOCATION + " TEXT";
```

Also getting this other error before crashing.

> Couldn't open AchieveGPA_DB for writing (will try read-only)

Edit:

Thanks for the response, added the missing parentheses. Though the error persists, here is the log:

> 04-07 17:34:20.213: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(9100): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "course_gpa_id": syntax error: , while compiling: CREATE TABLE courseTable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, course_prof_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(course_prof_id) REFERENCES professorTable(_id), course_gpa_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(course_gpa_id) REFERENCES gpaTable(_id), course_term_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(course_term_id) REFERENCES termTable(_id), name TEXT, number TEXT, location TEXT)

FOREIGN KEY STATEMENTS

```
// Foreign key statements.
private static final String FOREIGN_PROF = "FOREIGN KEY("+KEY_COURSEPROF_ID+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_PROFESSOR+"("+KEY_ID+")";
private static final String FOREIGN_GPA = "FOREIGN KEY("+KEY_COURSEGPA_ID+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_GPA+"("+KEY_ID+")";
private static final String FOREIGN_TERM = "FOREIGN KEY("+KEY_COURSETERM_ID+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_TERM+"("+KEY_ID+")";
```

Comment: Please post the exception message that includes the SQL that was compiled. Also, you're missing a close paren `)` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing column specifications and table constraints (the foreign key declarations). SQL syntax requires that column specifications are first and the table constraints last.

To fix it, move the `FOREIGN KEY` declarations last after all column specifications.